# Programming challenges Minesweeper help: How to check for a "*" in a 2D string array?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, arrays, minesweeper

I'm trying to write a Minesweeper program for the programming challenges website and I am having trouble detecting if a certain element in the 2D array is a mine and incrementing the surrounding areas.
Here is my code that checks for a mine in the corners of the array and increments the surrounding areas

```
  public void constructPointers(){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<row;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<colm;j++){
            if(minefield[i][j].equals("*")){
                if(i == 0 && j == 0){
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i+1][j]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i+1][j] = "" + val;

                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i][j+1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i][j+1] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i+1][j+1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i+1][j+1] = "" + val;
                }
                if(i == minefield.length -1 && j == 0){
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i-1][j]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i-1][j] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i][j+1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i][j+1] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i-1][j+1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i-1][j+1] = "" + val;
                }
                if(i == 0 && j == minefield[i].length - 1){
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i+1][j]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i+1][j] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i][j-1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i][j-1] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i+1][j-1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i+1][j-1] = "" + val;
                }
                if(i == minefield.length - 1 && j == minefield[i].length -1){
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i-1][j-1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i-1][j-1] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i-1][j]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i-1][j] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i][j-1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i][j-1] = "" + val;
                }
                if(i == 0){
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i+1][j]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i+1][j] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i][j+1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i][j+1] = "" + val;
                    val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[i+1][j+1]);
                    val++;
                    minefield[i+1][j+1] = "" + val;
                }
            }
```

if I inputed:

```
*.*
...
*.*
```

This code will output:

```
* 2 *
2 4 2
* 2 *
```

My question is: How can I get my code to "skip" adjacent mines and increment the surrounding areas?
If I inputed

```
*.*
*..
*.*
```

I want it to output:

```
    * 3 *
    * 5 2
    * 3 *
```

EDIT: All of you had great answers, but I picked the top answer because it solved alot of other problems I was having which I did not mention. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Instead of writing the code out 8 times, please write a Direction enumeration that contains all the single step increments you can move in. For example, http://pastebin.com/06yNW2TD in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just offering a suggestion for your mine update loop:

```
// You are on a mine
if(minefield[i][j].equals("*")){

    // Now go around your current position
    for(int tempRow = i-1; tempRow <= i+1; tempRow++) {
        for(int tempCol = j-1; tempCol <= j+1; tempCol++) {
            // If a valid square and not a mine
            if(tempRow >= 0 && tempRow < row &&
                tempCol >= 0 && tempCol < colm &&
                !minefield[tempRow][tempCol].equals("*")) 
            {
                // Do your update stuff
                int val = Integer.parseInt(minefield[tempRow][tempCol]);
                val++;
                minefield[tempRow][tempCol] = "" + val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This loop can scale up to larger board sizes quite a bit easier too...

Note: I assume minefield is initialized to "0" if not a mine.  Otherwise there would be problems with the first `parseInt`.

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe I did not think of this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you just iterate over every cell and for each cell that's not a mine count the number of mines around the cell. In other words you calculate the count for each cell all at once. This handles the question about how to deal with adjacent mines.

Comment: @ChrisGerken The snippet above is meant to live inside the OP's original loop that visits each cell.  The first test will check if the current cell is a mine.  Then the inner loop will go around it and increment each count for non-mine spaces.  I selected this pattern in favor of the "do every cell and accumulate count" pattern because I assume that there are less mine cells than non-mine cells, so targeting the mine-only cells in the outer loop will limit the number of times the inner loop needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to iterate over every cell and for each cell that's not a mine count the number of mines around the cell.  In other words you calculate the count for each cell all at once.  This handles your question about how to deal with adjacent mines.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(minefield[i][j] == "*"){
    // do stuff
}
```

I don't get it what's the big deal, hm.

## EDIT

Not correct - as said in comments:

```
if(minefield[i][j].equals("*")){
    // do stuff, they are equal.
}
```

p.s. not very constructive answer, but I left it because of constructive comments.

Comment: == is a poor way to compare Strings. equals() is the correct way, just as he already does in the code.

Comment: Oh sure, failed. I'll erase my answer as it's not constructive.

Comment: Agree with @Pescis never use == for Strings, as this checks for reference equality not actual equality. Use .equals();

Comment: He could use chars for this purpose hm. he could eventually then do ASCII magic :/

Comment: I'd say Integer would be better as an internal representation TBH. Like using -1 for mine and the rest for amount of adjacent mines. Computers like ints more than chars and Strings

Comment: @Pescis A character *is* an integer .. and a string is a sequence of characters. (Bounds for manipulation will vary based on mutability/immutability and indexing - immutable in Java, of course.)

Comment: Am I nuts or there is not any `.equals()` method (but there is `.compare()`)

Comment: Sure, whole the time wrong language was in my head. It's time to sleep I guess. (spoiler: C++)